# Format multiline code to single line in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, code-formatting

Is there a keyboard shortcut or fast way to change the code below to a single line in Visual Studio 2013?  I also have ReSharper installed.

**Multi**

```cs
new XElement("Option",
            new XAttribute("Name", "FileDelete"),
            "1"
        ),
```

**Single**

```cs
new XElement("Option", new XAttribute("Name", "FileDelete"),"1" ),
```

Answer (score 14):

Just select all the text

and press **(control + j)**

and it will become 1 line of code

Comment: What is the name of the command behind `Ctrl + J` my key-binding is different from default.

Comment: does it work in 2022

Comment: (control + j) open a internal terminal in my visual studio code.

Answer (score 12):

For VS2019, default binding is set to `Shift` + `Alt` + `L` + `J`

Or you could rebind this to something else by going to `Tools -> Options -> Keyboard -> search for 'join'`

Rebind `Edit.JoinLines` action to something like `(Text Editor) Ctrl + J` then press `Assign`

[image]

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to directly address the OP's question.

Comment: `Shift + Alt + L + J` works in VS2022

Answer (score 10):

I setup find/replace for quick use with a regex expression like so:

(note: I use VS 2015, so your hotkeys may be different)

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open quick find replace.
2. Make sure the "Use Regular Expressions" button is active/toggled-on, and that you are set to search in "Selection" (Not "Document" or "Entire Solution" or whatever)
3. Type
   `\s+`
   and a <kbd>space</kbd> ()
   in the "find" and "replace with" boxes respectively.
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to exit quick find/replace.
5. Now, as long as you don't change anything, you can select any text you want to make single line, and use the following hotkey sequence to quickly format it:

   1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (Open quick find/replace)
   2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Replace any occurrence of 1 or more White Spc chars with a single space.)
   3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Close the popup window that says "X Occurrences Found")
   4. <kbd>Esc</kbd> (Exit quick find/replace and return to your code)

I use this all the time after visual studio does things like implementing interfaces to turn stuff like

```
public SomeType SomeProperty {
    get {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    set {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

into stuff like

```
public SomeType SomeProperty { get { return someField; } set { /*Some Simple Set Code*/; } }
```

Comment: Confirmed this works in VS2012. Saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Great answer! Like watersnake said...saved me tons of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To make it with ReSharper, you should uncheck the option "Keep existing line breaks" in ReSharper/Options/Code Editing/C#/Formatting style/Line Breaks and Wrapping.

Or just add this line into your .dotSettings

```
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/KEEP_USER_LINEBREAKS/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
```

Then you could format your code using Code Cleanup Tool (default shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+F) or just by typing semicolons or braces.

Answer (score 2):

For me doing `Ctrl` + `J` opens the Linux terminal and does not format multiple lines to one line.

This is the fastest way on Linux

1. Hit `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`
2. Join Lines

Answer (score 0):

You can change your VS settings to automatically format code in whatever way you want, then select and retype any line/block-ending character (';' or '}') after the text you want formatted and VS will format it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [CodeMaid](http://vsixgallery.com/extension/4c82e17d-927e-42d2-8460-b473ac7df316/). The default keybinding is F3, but the command is called `CodeMaid.JoinLines` if you want to change it