# Is there a shortcut in VS to reformat a block of code to one line?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I'd like to be able to take this code block

```
 var uVacationLandLubbers = new UserAttribute {
     Name = "Land Lubbers",
         Project = pVacation,
         SystemUserAttribute = context.SystemUserAttributes.Single(x => x.Name == "Yes/No")
 };
```

and reformat it to

```
 var uVacationLandLubbers = new UserAttribute { Name = "Land Lubbers", Project = pVacation, SystemUserAttribute = context.SystemUserAttributes.Single(x => x.Name == "Yes/No") };
```

Is there a VS/Resharper/Other way of doing this?

Comment: The following question does this with ReSharper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206265/format-multiline-code-to-single-line-in-visual-studio

Comment: No it doesn't actually.

Answer (score 0):

This solution would not fully satisy your requirements, but help you considerably.

In Visual Studio, navigate to **Tools -> Options.**

In Options window, on the left select the language of your choice, say C#. Under C#, select **Formatting -> New Lines**. Once you select New Lines, a set of rules would be displayed on the right side, *uncheck the following rules*:

1. Place open brace on new line for types
2. Place open brace on new line for anonymous methods
3. Place open brace on new line for anonymous types
4. Place open brace on new line for object initializers
5. Place memebers in object initializers in new line
6. Place memebers in anonymous types in new line

Note: While unchecking a preview of the rule would be displayed which would help you to view the changes.

Once you do these settings, use this shortcut **Ctrl + K + D** to format the document.

Answer (score 0):

Use shortcut Ctrl + K + D to format the document code

Comment: This only triggers formatting the document code indeed. It is still depending on how the formatting is configured, if even possible to remove line breaks.